# hackerrank displayPathtoPrincess too many values to unpack

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, enumerate

so I just signed up for hackerrank and took a swing at the first AI problem which involves searching through a grid to find princess Peach and then printing out the steps the robot mario should take to save her.
This is my code:

```
    def displayPathtoPrincess(n,grid):
        MOVES = ['LEFT','RIGHT','UP','DOWN']
        m,p = (i for i,x in enumerate(grid) if x != '-')
        if grid[m] == 'p': m,p = p,m
        m,p = ((x/m, x%m) for x in [m,p])
        if m[0] > p[0]: v = 2
        else: v = 3
        if m[1] > p[1]: h = 0
        else: h = 1
        path = [v] * abs(m[0] - p[0])
        path.extend([h]*abs(m[1]-m[1]))
        return '\n'.join([MOVES[p] for p in path])
```

When I run the code I receive a ValueError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/game-player1-ooQVK8ZfwGFijjFs07eCIWom4Z3NG8W3/solution.py", line 26, in <module>
    displayPathtoPrincess(m,grid)
    File "/game-player1-ooQVK8ZfwGFijjFs07eCIWom4Z3NG8W3/solution.py", line 5, in    displayPathtoPrincess
m,p = (i for i,x in enumerate(grid) if x != '-')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong since I thought that enumerate returns the value inside the grid as well as the index so it's not like I'm trying to assign one value to two variables.. This fix is probably easy.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a link to the challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/saveprincess

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the generator expression `(i for i,x in ..)` returns a single object (an enumerator) and you are trying to destructure it and assign it to two variables `m,p`. It's unclear what you actually want here, but the error message is not wrong (it's just referring to the `m,p` part and not the `i,x` part).

Comment: Sweet, I understand why the code is wrong now. What I was trying to do with that line is iterate through the grid and find all the characters that are not hyphens (which represent empty spaces) and assign them to m (mario) and p (peach). The only other possible characters in the grid besides hyphens are the strings 'm' and 'p' so I figured my logic would work and I would just switch m and p if mario was given princesses's identity or vice versa ..